# jQuery fullcalendar custom event like title

Tags: fullcalendar, custom-events

I would like to add a custom event.
what I need to do is that there are various events on my calendar. There can be a payment event, check-in and check-out events, there can be friend's birthday event.

A birthday event can be there but I want only friend's birthday events and not all  colleague's birthday events.

How can I differentiate it in full calender?

Like there is title event. But I want a specific event and not all title event.

Say title event is used for rendering text - payments, check-in, check-out, etc.
I want to greet on arrival and say bye at departure using different icons.

so I need to a custom event which afterwards I can catch.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using event sources and pull from the server each event type as you need to display them.

so here is one of my event sources.

```
function calendarEventType(typeName) {
    return {
        url: '/cal-data',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            type: typeName
        },
        cache: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error Getting Calendar Data: " + errorThrown);
        }
    }
}
```

and i call it via:

```
.fullCalendar('addEventSource', calendarEventType('special-event');
```

then of course in your backend (PHP/Python/whatever) you need to pass a JSON event object list back.

check the docs for formating each event source difference (set class/color etc, different for each source).